# Choice of Area vector for finding motional emf

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Suppose that I take a cylindrical conductor with radius $r$ and height $h$.

I want to find out the magnitude of the motional emf generated in the conductor, if it moves in a uniform magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ with a velocity $\mathbf{v}$ along the x-axis.

In order to do so, I used the equation,
$$\varepsilon=-\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\phi_{\small{B}}}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

For a constant magnetic field, this becomes:
$$\varepsilon=-\mathbf{B\cdot}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{A}}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
My question is, what is the area vector to be used for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

$\vec A$ is the area of the circuit in the magnetic field.  It's not clear from your question exactly how your cylinder is aligned in the magnetic field so but assuming it is along $\hat z$, then 
$$
d\vec A/dt=\hat z\, d (dx dy)/dt = \hat z v_x dy\, .
$$
The direction $\hat z$ is obtained from the right-hand rule assuming the current in your circuit goes counter-clockwise.

As stated it is not clear from your question that your cylinder actually closes on a circuit; if this is the case you cannot define an area.  The potential difference between two end of a conductor moving in an magnetic field would be obtained from
$$
\vec F_m= q\vec v\times \vec B \qquad \leftrightarrow \qquad
\vec E_m = \vec v\times \vec B\, .
$$
In this case there is a potential difference between the ends of your conductor given by
$$
V=\int_1^2 (\vec v\times \vec B)\cdot d\vec \ell
$$
where the conductor extends from point $1$ to point $2$ (assuming both points are inside the region where $\vec B\ne 0$) and $d\vec \ell$ is a small piece of the conductor with the direction of $d\ell$ parallel to the conductor at that point.